# Laravel Eloquent hasManyThrough relation + pagination

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, eloquent, has-many-through

I have three tables:

```
Videos:
-id
-name
-another fields

Cats:
-id
-name
-another fields

Cats_videos:
-id
-cat_id
-video_id
```

And three Eloquent models:

```
class cat extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cat';

    public function AllCatVideos()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\videos', 'App\cats_videos','cat_id','id');
    }
}

class videos extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table ='videos';
}

class cats_videos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'cats_videos';
}
```

So, I want to receive all videos in one cat and then paginate the results. I trying to do like this:

```
$cat = new Cats();
    $videos = $cat->find(58)->AllCatVideos()->toSql();
```

And I receiving the sql like this:

```
select * from `videos` inner join `cats_videos` on `cats_videos`.`id` = `videos`.`id` where `cats_videos`.`cat_id` = 58
```

But I need "`cats_videos`.`video_id` = `videos`.`id`" instead of "`cats_videos`.`id` = `videos`.`id`". How can I do this using "hasManyThrough"? Or I should look something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I just need use belongsToMany.

```
class cat extends Model{
public function Videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\videos','cats_videos','cat_id','video_id');
}}
```